# Crash when trying to push view controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I am having a weird issue where my app crashes when I am trying to push a new view controller. I have set up a swipe gesture and want to segue to another view controller when a swipe is detected. When I run these 2 lines of code ...

```
let viewController:ViewController = ViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

The app crashes not specifically on either of those lines of code but rather in my ViewController class when in my viewDidLoad method I run this piece of code...

```
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

If I comment that out it crashes when I set the auto-correction type of my textField. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like `imageView` is nil. Maybe you can post the code of `ViewController`?

Comment: try to set imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true in viewDidAppear

Comment: if `imageView` is an @IBOutlet, it should have set before `viewDidLoad` is called. If not, something is wrong.

Comment: ImageView is an IBOutlet, which concerns me.

Answer (score 1):

First place I look when the view immediately crashes is in the Outlets for that ViewController in InterfaceBuilder.  I look for anything that shows up with an exclamation mark.  That usually means I renamed an outlet or broke a connection somehow.  Delete anything broken by pressing the little x by the item that's messed up.  I'll attach a photo so you can see.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're loading a ViewController that exists in storyboard  with

```
let viewController:ViewController = ViewController()
```

which will result in nil outlets , so you have to use

```
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCID") as! ViewController
```

and give that vc a storyboard identifier like **VCID**

Comment: I followed your suggestion (changed that line of code and gave the storyboard a corresponding id) but now the app crashes on the line of code in your answer, when I try to instantiate the viewcotnroller. Any idea why?

Comment: in the log it just says lldb, Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: make sure the hardcoded id is the same , also default storyboard is Main , is your vc inside it ??

Comment: I have made sure the hardcoded id is the same, and my vc is inside of Main.storyboard

Comment: can you share a github demo with the problem but fastly

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved the issue but it has a weird side effect. Instead of using the line of code in @Sh_Khan's answer, I used ...

```
let viewController = nav?.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainVC") as! ViewController
```

The variable `nav` is equal to the navigation controller of the current view-controller. This seems to work without any hiccups but for some reason **the back button does not disappear from the navigation controller after the segue is preformed**. Does anybody know a solution to this, if so leave a comment and I will update my answer.

EDIT:
Another issue is that it wipes everything changed on that ViewController by the user clear. Is there another way to instantiate a ViewController without clearing it?

Comment: It might be wiping everything because instantiating a VC like this creates a whole new instance of that VC, which will not be the same one that may already exist.

Answer (score -1):

Follow what @Sh_Khan has said and in addition to that make sure that the view that you are making the push segue from is embedded in a Navigation controller.

Comment: Segues are deprecated, please coordinate your view controllers outside of the controllers themselves.